# Effectivitly Final Variable in Java Lambda - Mastering Lambdas by Maurice Naftalin

Tags: lambda, java-8

While reading Mastering Lambdas by Maurice Naftalin, I came across following example.
Chapter 3, Section 3.2.4 here are the two examples.

```
//don't do this - race conditions!
library.stream().forEach(b -> pageCounter += b.getPageCount());
```

Another one

```
//formally correct but inefficient and ugly
library.stream().forEachOrdered(b -> { pageCount+=b.getPageCount();});
```

My confusion was the reason given for not writing the above code. As lambdas are not suppose to chagne the state and can only access final or effectively final variables, how the above code can be valid in the first place?

Can somebody help me understand, if I am missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Round brackets like in `.forEach(b -> (pageCounter += b.getPageCount()));` are not valid in this context, as `(expression)` is not a valid consumer. When a `Consumer` is required, you need either, curly braces like in `.forEach(b -> {pageCounter += b.getPageCount();})` or no brackets like in `.forEach(b -> pageCounter += b.getPageCount())`.

Comment: Edited with correct syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example is not valid syntax due to the wrong brackets. But you can omit them anyway:

```
//don't do this - race conditions!
library.stream().forEach(b -> pageCounter+=b.getPageCount());
```

```
//formally correct but inefficient and ugly
library.stream().forEachOrdered(b -> pageCount+=b.getPageCount());
```

Both are valid syntax and will compile, if `pageCount` is a mutable *field*, either an instance field or a `static` field, but, of course, the book is right, neither is recommended.

The restriction for captured variables to be either, `final` or *effectively final*, applies only to *local variables* (including parameters).

Comment: Aah! Instance variables or static could be possibility... Missed such simple thing :-) Thanks.